# Spring CrudRepository query with custom results

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have one table (Employee) where I want to query. the result will join the same table to get 2 rows from Employee in one row in the output.

```
+------+---------+------+
| name | manager | dept |
+------+---------+------+
| Zak  |         | xyz  |
| Arp  | Zak     | abc  |
| Tom  | Zak     | abc  |
| Smi  | Arp     | abc  |
| Moh  | Zak     | xyz  |
+------+---------+------+
```

I tried to get employees of each manager with specific options (dept)

```
select t1.name, t2.name from TB t1
     RIGHT JOIN TB t2 on t1.name = t2.manager
    where t1.dept="xyz" AND t2.dept="abc"
    ORDER BY t1.name
```

Results will be something like this:

```
+------+------+------+
| name | name | dept |
+------+------+------+
| Zak  | Arp  | xyz  |
| Zak  | Tom  | abc  |
+------+------+------+
```

when I try using CrudRepository in spring, then I need to define an Entity for the result, but the result is not a table in my DB. and I am not able to use Entity Employee as the result has different columns (or allies)
I am not sure how can i read such results in spring.. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Query` annotation. Put the following method in crud repository.

```
@Query("select t1.name, t2.name from TB t1 RIGHT JOIN TB t2 on t1.name = t2.manager where t1.dept="xyz" AND t2.dept="abc" ORDER BY t1.name", nativeQuery=true) 
 List<Object[]> find();
```

Comment: I guess you must have a table represnts Object Entity in DB, I got this error:
{Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'EmployeeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'EmployeeRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EmployeeRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object}

Comment: My bad, it should have been `List<Object[]>`, edited the original answer too.

Comment: its the same error: Not a managed type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;